# I need to sum the number of visits in march and, in another column have the number of visits in april, how can I do it in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to sum the number of visits in march and another column that show me the number of visits in april, how can I do it in one query?

I am running in Metabase and I never really used it before, I don't even know how to use the dashboard correctly so I am just querying as usual.

I want to be able to pull enough information to create a visitation over time graph.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your tbl name, what's your date field named and what's it's data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  sum(case when month='MARCH' then 1 else 0 end) as VisitInMarch,
  sum(case when month='APRIL' then 1 else 0 end) as VisitInApril
from your_table
```

or if some specific sum:

```
select
  sum(case when month='MARCH' then [your_field] else 0 end) as VisitInMarch,
  sum(case when month='APRIL' then [your_field] else 0 end) as VisitInApril
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each visit has a unique ID:

```sql
select 
      count( distinct case when month = 'March' then visit_ID else NULL end ) as March_Visits
    , count( distinct case when month = 'April' then visit_ID else NULL end ) as April_Visits
from visits
```

Or if you want everything in one column, just group by month:

```sql
select 
      month
    , count( distinct visit_ID ) as Visits
from visits
group by month
order by month
```